# How do you do string interpolation with variables in Nim?

Tags: string, nim-lang

I've seen that you can interpolate strings with `fmt` like so:

```nim
let msg = "hello"
echo fmt"{msg}\n"
```

But in my case, the interpolated string is quite long. I would prefer to assign said text to a variable and then the the interpolation later, like so:

```nim
let msg = "..... long text here {place_holder1}...."
echo interpolate(msg, var1, etc)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, see [strutils.format](https://nim-lang.org/docs/strutils.html#format%2Cstring%2Cvarargs%5Bstring%2C%5D).

strutils also comes with the `%` operator which can be used like:

```py
let str = "$#, $#, $#"
let interp = str % ["One", "Two", "Three"]
echo(interp) # echos One, Two, Three
```